# Find commutative matrix for two other matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to find a matrix C that commutes with both A and B

Matrix A:
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0  \\
        0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Matrix B:
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0  \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Matrix C:
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b  \\
        c & d \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I know if $AC = CA$ and $AC - CA$ equals the $0$ matrix then $C$ commutes with $A$ 
(from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices).

How do I go about finding a commutative matrix?

EDIT: I messed up when making the question, $A$ is indeed not equal to $B$ (fixed now)

Comment: There something wrong here because your matrix A is equal to matrix B.

Comment: You need to expand $AC-CA$. You obtain the matrix $\{\{0, b\}, \{-c,0\}\}$. For this matrix to be the Zero matrix you have two constraints, $b=0$ and $-c=0$, which means $b=c=0$ and $a,d=$whatever. If you want that $C$ commutes with another matrix $B$ you will compute $BC-CB=0$ which will give you other constraints to be satisfied.

Comment: Yeah @GiovanniResta I messed up, A was indeed not equal to B..

Fixed it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in the comment, you expand the product $AC−CA$ and you obtain the matrix
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & b\\
-c & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$
Setting this matrix equal to the zero matrix you obtain the two constraints $b=0$ and $c=0$.

You do the same with the $B$ matrix, and you obtain that $BC-CB$ is 
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -b\\
c & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$
So you obtain the same constraints $b=c=0$ (this exercise is really boring).

The conclusion is that any matrix of the form 
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & 0\\
0 & d
\end{array}\right)
$$
will commute with $A$ and with $B$.